# Saving and restoring fragments in a custom way

Tags: android, android-fragments

I developing an app, in which i have several fragments to handle all the content (-all hosted by a single activity)

Some of these fragments are simple ListFragments with a BaseAdapter stored inside.

in my app life cycle there would be shifting between these fragments constantly.
So to retain the data each fragment hold, i keep a reference in MainActivity (that hosts all fragments) of each fragment, and whenever a call to open this one fragments come i first check if it is not null and then simply call the current reference to .replace(...).commit();

and in this way i get to hold the data inside the fragments: ListFragment will keep it's Adapter stored with all relevant data inside. with out having to redownload it (from server).

My question: is this a good way of handling this situation or will i be meet up with future problems

Comment: you are keeping fragment instant in your activity. am i right?

Comment: yes Like this: private ListFragment mContentFragment;

Comment: then You will Also store the list of your model class in that fragment. am i right?